# How to group API calls in API-Management's Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In the API-Management's Developer Portal, we have the problem that all Operation (API) calls are listed in a long list, making it difficult for our customers to find out what calls that belong together. What we'd like is the possibility to group calls by something, i.e. the controller name. (In Swagger this can be done by using the `tags` field in the Swagger specification.)

In the templates section, there's an option `Operation list (grouped)`, which, by the name of it, might be able to solve our problems. But how can I use this template?

[image]

I'm currently importing the API list using the `OpenAPI specification`.

**Update 1:**

This is what it looks like in a sample operation list for us. There's no search box available. 
[image: Our operation list has no search box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(grouped) template is used when user selects "Group by tags" option - rightmost button next to search field on APIs/operations list. Here is how it looks on UI:
[image]

Comment: I have no "Group by tags" option when I go into the API/operations list. Can you share a screen shot or something to show where that's button is supposed to be? I can see a search field on the API list page, but no button. And on the Operations list page there is neither search field nor group by button.

Comment: Updated with image. Let me know if you don't have it. If you don't have any tags defined in service that may be the reason for this control to not show up. So try setting them up.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy! Our Operation List doesn't look like that. However, we found a Microsoft article about Tagging currently being in Public Preview and your screenshots look similar to those. So I assume it will come to us later on and thus mark your answer as complete!

Comment: You should try adding some tags via Azure Portal. There is an option in service menu. Internal logic shows this button only if you have some tags defined. And it makes sense for you to use tags as they're intended in part to group things.

Comment: Ok, I get it - I have to define the tags myself for each operation. Is it possible for API Management to understand the tags in the OpenAPI file?

Comment: That feature is coming shortly. Open API import will start understanding tag in about a week.

Comment: That's really exciting :) Thanks a lot for the information!